# Suitable machine learning algorithm for column selection

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, machine-learning

I am new in machine learning. In my work I require a machine learning algorithm to select some columns out of many columns in a 2D matrix depending on the spread of the data. Below is a sample of the 2D matrix:

```
400 700 4 1400

410 710 4 1500


416 716 4 1811

..............

410 710 4 1300
```

Previously I have used standard deviation method to select columns depending on some threshold values(as a measure of spread of data for a particular column). Observe that the 3rd column is constant and last column in varying tremendously. 1st and 2nd column in also varying but the spread of their data is small. By applying standard deviation on each of the columns I get (sigma) = 10, 10, 0, 200 respectively.

I have considered some experimental threshold values to discard some columns. If the (sigma) crosses the threshold value range then the corresponding column gets discarded. I calculated those threshold values manually. Though this method was very simple but dealing with the threshold values is a very tedious task as there are many existing columns.

For this reason I want to use a standard machine learning algorithm or somehow if I can make these threshold values adaptive. So that I don't require to hard-code the threshold values inside the code. Can anyone please suggest me an appropriate algorithm for this?

Comment: That's a pretty vague problem description.

Comment: Tommy there is many sites that stack-Exchange runs actually [118 Q&A sites](http://stackexchange.com/) , Always choose one that is most appropriate I beleive for your this question correct site and tag is: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning Additionally, don't use statements like "Please reply ASAP" etcs.